# Capturing all output from subprocess in python3

Tags: python-3.x, svn, terminal, subprocess, capture

I want to capture all output into variables that subprocess prints out. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess # Subprocess management
import sys # System-specific parameters and functions

try:
    args = ["svn", "info", "/directory/that/does/not/exist"]
    output = subprocess.check_output(args).decode("utf-8")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    error = "CalledProcessError: %s" % str(e)
except:
    error = "except: %s" % str(sys.exc_info()[1])
else:
    pass
```

This script still prints this into the terminal:

> svn: E155007: '/directory/that/does/not/exist' is not a working copy

How can I capture this into a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check_output only captures stdout and NOT stderr (according to https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output )

In order to capture stderr you should use

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, ...)
```

I recommend reading the docs prior to asking here by the way.

Comment: This works, thank you. I did check the manual and several posts about this but I still didn't get it to work on my own.